# bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file when trying to run "make"

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, syntax

I'm trying to make deploy to Google Cloud(Linux) and got the following errors:

```
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

My code is the following:
I posted ssh-cmd on the bottom as well.

```
deploy:
   $(MAKE) ssh-cmd CMD='docker-credential-gcr configure-docker'
   @echo "pulling new container image..."
   $(MAKE) ssh-cmd CMD='docker pull $(REMOTE_TAG)'
   @echo "removing old container..."
   -$(MAKE) ssh-cmd CMD='docker container stop $(CONTAINER_NAME)'
   -$(MAKE) ssh-cmd CMD='docker container rm $(CONTAINER_NAME)'
   @echo "starting new container..."
   @$(MAKE) ssh-cmd CMD='\
       docker run -d --name=$(CONTAINER_NAME) $(REMOTE_TAG) \
           --restart=unless-stopped \
           -p 80:3000 \
           -e PORT=3000 \
           -e \"MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://storybook-user-$(ENV):$(call get-secret,atlas_user_password_$(ENV))@storybooks-$(ENV).5cn1o.mongodb.net/$(DB_NAME)?retryWrites=true&w=majority\" \
           -e GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=$(OAUTH_CLIENT_ID) \
           -e GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=$(call get-secret,google_oauth_client_secret) \
           $(REMOTE_TAG) \
           '
```

---

```
ssh-cmd:
  gcloud compute ssh $(SSH_STRING)\
    --project=$(PROJECT_ID) \
    --zone=$(ZONE) \
    --command="$(CMD)"
```

Comment: Make sure all the backslashes are the last character on the line, no space after it.

Comment: What does `ssh-cmd` do?

Comment: Added ssh-cmd to the bottom of the message

Comment: Your `ssh-cmd` rule is badly indented.

Comment: It was just wrong editing, i fixed it.